# How to set id's from parent with Jackson on Android

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have a Json response that looks like

```
{
id: 2721
version: 0
value: "29946799496073894104"
type: "YYY"
description: "XXX"
    items: [
    {
        id: 7
        version: 0
        type: "HEADER"
        value: "value1"
        position: 0
    }
    {
        id: 8
        version: 0
        type: "Body"
        value: "value2"
        position: 1
    }
    ]
....
```

in my Java Item class I have also a parentId variable.
How can I set parentId from parent Object, in this case for all 3 items I have to set parentId = 2721. Can I use annotations for that? I use Jackson 2.1.4.